# iOS: Cell content not being cleared with reuseidentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I'm trying to build a table with cells that list an array in UILabels. So each cell will have its size and amount of labels determined by the number of objects in that array. However, I'm running into an issue where the content is initially input correctly, but then as the table cells get recycled during the scroll, the content doesn't clear.

[image: Broken UITableView overlapping cell content]

Here's my entire implementation. If someone could please give me an explanation as to how I can prevent the labels from being retained during the recycling process I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UITableView *tableView;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    NSArray *myTableArray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up View
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // Set up Table
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    [tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    //Set up dummy array for cells (in my actual app I'm pulling from Core Data)
    NSArray *cell1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Some Text", nil];
    NSArray *cell2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Different", @"Text", nil];
    NSArray *cell3 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Lorem...", nil];
    NSArray *cell4 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Thanks", @"for your", @"help", nil];
    NSArray *cell5 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A bit more", @"text", nil];
    NSArray *cell6 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bunch of", @"junk text", nil];
    NSArray *cell7 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"So long", @"and thanks", @"for all", @"the fish", nil];
    NSArray *cell8 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Ipsum..", nil];
    NSArray *cell9 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Peter Pan", @"killed", @"The Lost Boys", nil];
    NSArray *cell10 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"All Dogs", @"Go to Heaven", @"Disney", nil];
    myTableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4, cell5, cell6, cell7, cell8, cell9, cell10, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",myTableArray);

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return myTableArray.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)table heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *arr = [myTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return 60 * arr.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Set up the labels
    [cell setLabels:myTableArray[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}


@end
```

CustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
- (void)setLabels:(NSArray *)labels;
@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)setLabels:(NSArray *)labels {
    int labelHeight = 60;
    int y = 0;
    for (NSString *string in labels) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, self.bounds.size.width-20, labelHeight)];
        label.text = string;
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:20];
        y += labelHeight;
        [self.contentView addSubview:label];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `CustomCell.m`:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    for(UIView *subview in [self.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

`prepareForReuse` is a method called on cells as the table view is dequeuing them for reuse.

I'll assume that you've minimized what you're actually doing to a very simplistic example, because otherwise, as Leo Natan has suggested, you should simply be using the existing labels.

Comment: Yes I have. The app I'm working on has way more than just labels, I just built that as a quick example isolating the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are adding a new `UILabel` subview without removing the old one.

Why are you adding new labels? Use the already existing label. Since you are using `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, the cell already contains several labels. Use `self.textLabel.text = string` instead.

If you wish to keep using a custom label, you should remove all subviews in the cell's `prepareForReuse` (don't forget to call the super implementation of `prepareForReuse`). Just remember, that since you have defined the cell as `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, it will have other subviews that you should not remove.

Comment: Well I'm adding new labels because the cells don't have a fixed number. So if a situation came up where one cell has 30 labels I want it to be able to respond to that without having to create a reuse identifier for like 100 different cells.

Comment: @IanGray In that case, you should remove the previous labels, as they are no longer needed.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove all labels before add labels in reused cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    for (UIView * subView in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [subView removeFromSuperview] ;
        }
    }

    // Set up the labels
    [cell setLabels:myTableArray[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Given we're talking about a custom cell class, why wouldn't you use `prepareForReuse`?

Comment: Yeah, it's better to do that in `prepareForReuse`, but I haven't use it before.